# Avoid duplicate custom post type posts in multiple loops in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running two loops with a custom post type of Portfolio (ID of 3). The first loop is for Featured and the second is for the rest. I plan on having more than 3 Featured posts in random order. I would like to have the Featured ones that aren't displaying in the first loop to show up in my second loop. How can I set this up so there are no duplicate posts?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
get_header(); ?>

    <div class="section-bg">

        <div class="portfolio">

            <div class="featured-title">
                <h1>featured</h1>
            </div> <!-- end #featured-title -->

            <div class="featured-gallery">

                <?php
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>

                    <div class="featured peek">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h1>
                                <?php 
                                $thetitle = $post->post_title; 
                                $getlength = strlen($thetitle); 
                                $thelength = 40;
                                echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength); 
                                if ($getlength > $thelength) echo '...'; ?>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="contact-divider"></div>
                            <p><?php the_tags('',' / '); ?></p>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'cover')); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- end .featured -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div> <!-- end .featured-gallery -->

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div> <!-- end .portfolio -->

    </div> <!-- end #section-bg -->

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="section-bg">

        <div class="portfolio-gallery">

            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'rand');
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>

                <div class="featured peek">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h1>
                            <?php 
                            $thetitle = $post->post_title; 
                            $getlength = strlen($thetitle); 
                            $thelength = 40;
                            echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength); 
                            if ($getlength > $thelength) echo '...'; ?>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="contact-divider"></div>
                        <p><?php the_tags('',' / '); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'cover')); ?></a>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- end .featured -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div> <!-- end .portfolio-gallery -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div> <!-- end #section-bg -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If possible, could the answer outline how to implement it into my existing code? Thank you. :)

Comment: may be this link be useful to prevent duplicate posts
[here](http://wpengineer.com/1719/filter-duplicate-posts-in-the-loop/)

Answer (score 0):

On your second loop, exclude the cat with ID 3. Use a negative value for it

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => -3, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
```

See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page) for reference

Comment: I plan on having more than 3 Featured posts in random order. I would like to have the Featured ones that aren't displaying in the first loop to show up in my second loop. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, in your first loop you must save in an array the post that are you visualizing, and the in the second loop adding  a parameter to skip this posts post__not_in!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have much of a coding background... Do you think you could show me how to implement it into my existing code? I apologize for the hassle!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on http://webmasters-blog.com/how-to-avoid-duplicate-posts-in-multiple-loops/

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
get_header(); ?>

    <div class="section-bg">

        <div class="portfolio">

            <div class="featured-title">
                <h1>featured</h1>
            </div> <!-- end #featured-title -->

            <div class="featured-gallery">

                <?php
                    $ids = array();
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                ?>

                    <div class="featured peek">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h1>
                                <?php 
                                $thetitle = $post->post_title; 
                                $getlength = strlen($thetitle); 
                                $thelength = 40;
                                echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength); 
                                if ($getlength > $thelength) echo '...'; ?>
                            </h1>
                            <div class="contact-divider"></div>
                            <p><?php the_tags('',' / '); ?></p>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'cover')); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- end .featured -->

                <?php $ids[]= $post->ID; endwhile; ?>

            </div> <!-- end .featured-gallery -->

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div> <!-- end .portfolio -->

    </div> <!-- end #section-bg -->

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="section-bg">

        <div class="portfolio-gallery">

            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'rand');
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {
            ?>

                <div class="featured peek">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <h1>
                            <?php 
                            $thetitle = $post->post_title; 
                            $getlength = strlen($thetitle); 
                            $thelength = 40;
                            echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength); 
                            if ($getlength > $thelength) echo '...'; ?>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="contact-divider"></div>
                        <p><?php the_tags('',' / '); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'cover')); ?></a>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- end .featured -->

            <?php } endwhile; ?>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div> <!-- end .portfolio-gallery -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div> <!-- end #section-bg -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If there's a cleaner way to go about doing it, I'd still appreciate feedback!

Comment: No, it's more or less what I have told you! The only difference is that you are querying the featured posts two times and skip in the code. That is irrilevant if you don't have a LOT of traffic to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is a thing you can be improved:

```
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post__not_in' => $ids);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

And... adding a filter for `the_title()` in your functions.php would be fine too, to do the substr thing, so you can simple use `the_title()`.